# Accessing the Vue within jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, scope, this, vuejs2

I have a vue object and in the mounted method I test for a scroll event on the browser

```
mounted() {

self= this;

 $(window).scroll(function(){
          $.get("/works?start="+$('#loaded_max').val(), function(loaded){
            self.work = loaded;
            console.log(self);
          });

    });
```

console.log(self) //returns window

console.log(this) //returns ajax

How do I access the vue object? Specifically the data so I can update the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Self appears to be window, any other variable works

so

```
 mounted() {

let myvue = this;

 $(window).scroll(function(){
          $.get("/works?start="+$('#loaded_max').val(), function(loaded){
            myvue.work = loaded;
            console.log(myvue.work);
          });

    });
```

I have always used that technique to reference the 'current object' when scope is an issue but it obviously has issues when you need to reference something other than the window.